# Installing freeCodecamp locally hangs when I get to the npm ci step

Tags: npm, npm-ci

I've been trying to install freeCodeCamp repo locally coz I'm doing the Full-stack curriculum and I am in a remote area where the grid is not reliable.

I've got the repo on my compute already. I've also installed MongoDB and Nodejs and Npm, following instructions and steps posted on Github by the freeCodeCamp Team. When I get to the step where dependencies need to be installed using "npm ci", the progress bar runs untill halfway, then it stops forever (sometimes it freezes the whole system).

I've tried with Git Bash, Powershell, and Powershell ISE with same results. I did uninstall and re-install Nodejs and NPM a couple of times for no avail. The versions are Node v16.17.0 and Npm 8.18.0.

Any HELP will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues with v16.17.0 and npm v8.18.0. Downgrading to v8.13.0 seemed to fix it for me but I can't find any previously raised issues as to why this may be the case.

To downgrade:
`npm i -g npm@8.13.0 && npm install`

Seems to occur from v8.14.0 onwards

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try and come back to you.

Comment: My issue stemmed from have an npm script called 'dependencies' this hung the install from npm v8.14.0+... so might not be the same issue. Check the scripts in package.json you're trying to install to see if you have the same issue

Comment: Hi @Joel. Yes I have the following in my package'json - "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "invariant": "2.2.4"
  },       Should I delete it?

Comment: No, check the 'script' portion on the package.json. The 'dependencies' you mention is the list of packages it will install to run and is required. I would also try removing the node_modules folder and trying it again